# Blurry text on canvas despite AA fix having been applied

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, text, blurry

Despite having translated by half a pixel for antialiasing - so lines look crisp - my text in Chrome (which looked OK formerly) looks fuzzy. Here's two images - one from Chrome and the other from Opera:

[image]

[image]

Is there a setting that I can adjust to resolve this?

Comment: I should note that those images are from my laptop - which is a wide screen. My desktop LCD (not a widescreen) looks better - but still not perfectly crisp.

Comment: The angled lines & curves of text are only partially helped by the translating a half-pixel. Additionally make sure you're adjusting for each devices devicePixelRatio: html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi. If these adjustments don't satisfy you can new-up an svg text element and drawImage it on the canvas.